# Can @Async method see data inserted by the calling thread which is @Transactional? -Spring Boot / JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an Async call at the end of a Service which is annotated @Transactional. The service updates some data (with JPA/Hibernate). After all the manipulation is done on the data, the same service makes an Async calls which fetches data including the records updated earlier in the service. My question is - Would the Async step be able to see the updated data? If not, is there a way to run the Async method in the same Transaction as for the invoking thread so that it can see the data? Below is the pseudo/rough code:

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class ContactService {

   public ContactDetailsDTO updateContactAndFetchProjects(ContactDTO contact){
 
      contactRepository.updateContact(contact);

      asyncProjectFetcher.fetchContactProjects(contact);
      CompletableFuture.allOf(asyncProjectFetcher).join();
      .......
      .......          
      return contactDetailsDTO;

   }

}

public class AsyncProjectFetcher {

     @Async
     public CompletableFuture<ContactDetailsDTO> fetchContactProjects(ContactDTO contact) 
     {
         .......
         //can this see the data updates done in updateContactAndFetchProjects?
     }


}
```

Comment: No it cannot because the data isn't persisted.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum.  Is there a way to push the same transaction to the Async call?

Comment: No there isn't as transactions are bound to threads as well as the resource handling (JDBC Connection, JPA EntityManager etc.).